# Проблема с путями до файлов в php

Tags: php, файловая-система

[image: Дерево файлов]

Есть такое дерево файлов на сайте. В файле личного кабинета пользователя 
**site.ru/user/1** 
Подключаю шапку и подвал. Но т.к. мы находимся в несуществующем каталоге user (ЧПУ), то у меня проблема с картинками в шапке и подвале. Как лучше подключать файлы? Не могу понять логики действий, которые можно сделать

Comment: Какая проблема?

Comment: На личной странице пользователя файлы не находятся. Т.е. для всех файлов на странице я прописал **../file**, а для файлов шапки я не понимаю, что делать.

Comment: Не используйте никаких `../`, а прописывайте все ссылки относительно корня сайта с `/` в начале, или пропишите html-тег `base`, чтобы указать, относительно какого адреса считать ссылки

Comment: А как работать на локальном сервере? Если я делаю относительно корня `/`, то за основу берется localhost

Comment: Ну и пусть берётся localhost, это не проблема

Comment: Почему не проблема? Я работаю через xampp. В локалхосте много проектов, я не же не буду делать всегда `/title-project/vendor/img/ex.png`??? Потом, когда на хостинг буду ставить будут же проблемы глобальные, разве нет?